# jump from one jsp to another without using jsp:forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to jump from first JSP page to second JSP page without using jsp:forward. The reason I want to do this is, whenever I refresh my second page I get a confirmation message asking "do you wish to re-submit form". Also the URL of the second page shows as first page's URL. Also I want this to happen without clicking anywhere.
Below is what I have did. I need to do something else:

```
<jsp:forward page="home.jsp">
    <jsp:param value="<%=uid %>" name="uid1" />
    <jsp:param value="<%=des %>" name="des" />
</jsp:forward>
```

Please help!

Comment: So you want to redirect instead of forward?

Comment: If that solves my problem (new to JSP). How do I do that?

Comment: OK, I tried it like this - response.sendRedirect("home.jsp?uid1="+uid+"&des="+des); . But I don't want uid and des values to be displayed in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES!! I did it.
I used

```
response.sendRedirect("home.jsp")
```

And for pass hidden paramerters, I created a session attribute in first page and took the values in second page using

```
session.setAttribute("login_id", uid);
```

and

```
String uid=session.getAttribute("login_id").toString();
```

respectively.